# How to overcome this error? "Undefined index: name in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.0\www\ipetlin\signup.php on line 118"

Tags: php, mysql

I just use easyphp for my project. If I open the page, the error like "Undefined index: name in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.0\www\ipetlin\signup.php on line 118" will appear on the screen. However, after filling all the field, the error disappear. How to solve this problem. I went to some forum, they said, by adding the last code, the error will disappear. Please help me. Thank you.

```
// Get values from form 
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];
$gender=$_REQUEST['gender'];
$ic=$_REQUEST['ic'];
$addr=$_REQUEST['addr'];
$dept=$_REQUEST['dept'];
$kod=$_REQUEST['kod'];
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few functions that you can use - such as `isset()` and `empty()` on variables to make sure that indexes are defined before you try to use them.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['name']) // and or any other checking
{
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
error_reporting(0);
```

not

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Although I wouldn't recommend using `error_reporting(0);` during development phase as it helps you to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

As a one line solution:

```
$name= isset($_REQUEST['name']) ? $_REQUEST['name'] : '';
```

Apart from that, you should use $_POST or $_GET. $_REQUEST contains everything from $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE. So it might be dangerous.